# What is the proper method for using the output of one observable as the input to another in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I need to call a service with an async (http) return, and use it's output as an additional input to a service method (which returns an observable). What's the best way to do this in Angular 4+?

I have tried 'chaining' the results in the "subscribe" method of the first service, but doing this my service always returns 'null'.

```js
public secondServiceCall: Observable<object> {
   this.firstService.next().subscribe(result=> {
      item.number = result;

      return this.httpService.post<object>('/new', item);
   });
}
```

I expected that the function wouldn't return until the subscription for the firstService was completed (async like), but this didn't happen - and instead I got 'null' in my calling function.

I have also tried to use the firstService call as an observable - this returns the second observable correctly, but never waits for the "then" function to execute before firing the second observable.

```
this.firstService.next().toPromise().then(result=> {
  item.number = result;
});

return return this.httpService.post<object>('/new', item);
```

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Comment: I'm aware of the switchMap operator, but I'm unable to find any useful examples on how to wait for the first result, THEN fire the second observable. Can you expand on your link?

Comment: The link has plenty of examples. `return call1().pipe(switchMap(response1 => call2(response1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it's not important which combining operator to use: `flatMap`, `concatMap` or `switchMap`; they will behave the same because `Angular`'s `http` emits a value only once and immediately completes.

Usually you would like to prefer `concatMap` more because this operator respects the order of emissions (meaning that if you have some delayed calls in your Observables they will be executed one after another, while `flatMap` and `switchMap` can lead to uncertain results, more details here https://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap).

---

TLDR; Use `concatMap`

```
this.http.get('one').pipe(
  concatMap(result => this.http.get('two'))
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Import the switchMap operator:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Whatever the method in `firstService` that returns an observable of whatever `item` is, wrap that as such:

```
public secondServiceCall: Observable<object> {
   return this.firstService.someMethod().pipe(
      switchMap(item => {
         return this.httpService.post<object>('/new', item);
      })
   ) // result of your HTTP call based on item from firstService is now available when you subscribe
}
```

What this does is execute whatever your `firstService` method is which returns an `Observable<item>`, then *switches* over to the `httpService.post` call, which is supplied the result of the `firstService` method as the first argument.

Edit: Thanks JB Nizet, combined multiple iterations of the answer :/